select col dynamically to get value
I've dataframe with below schema
 ID, Name, AcctIdName, AcctIdLoc, AcctIdPop, AcctIdTop, AcctIdPin
1, IdName,   1,          0,         0,         0,          0
2, IdLoc,    0,         -1,         0,         0,          0
3, IdPop,    0,          0,         0,         3,          0
4, IdTop,    0,          0,         0,         2,          0
5, IdPin,    0,          0,         0,         0,          7
6, IdTrin,   0,          0,         0,         0,          8

I want to create a mapper, where AcctId will have a value from its corresponding col mentioned in mapper
For Ex
when Name is IdName, AcctId should have value from AcctIdName
when Name is IdLoc, AcctId should have value from AcctIdLoc
when Name is IdPop, AcctId should have value from AcctIdPop
when Name is IdTop, AcctId should have value from AcctIdTop
when Name is IdPin, AcctId should have value from AcctIdPin
else not match found for any Name's value in Mapper, then assign default value from AcctIdName

As per above mapper, output will be
ID, Name, AcctIdName, AcctIdLoc, AcctIdPop, AcctIdTop, AcctIdPin, AcctId
    1, IdName,   1,          0,         0,         0,          0,        1
    2, IdLoc,    0,         -1,         0,         0,          0,       -1
    3, IdPop,    0,          0,         0,         3,          0,        0
    4, IdTop,    0,          0,         0,         2,          0,        2
    5, IdPin,    0,          0,         0,         0,          7,        7
    6, IdTrin,   0,          0,         0,         0,          7,        0

I dont want to create code with many conditions, but would like to create mapper/utility where it will assign value for AcctId by taking info from mapper/utility. Would like to maintain only mapper, In case of more columns come in this schema, I can just update the mapper/utility to accommodate the changes I need.
Can anyone suggest anything ?
Thanks

not an answer as I'm not entirely sure if this is what you are after but consider looking at Quality folder or engine which is a big case generator and perhaps closest (the "utility" becomes config with priority)

You could solve this with a CASE clause and a chain of WHEN-THEN-ELSE expressions. Please see the example implementation below. It's a flexible solution, but the downside is the chain of WHEN-THEN-ELSE expressions is essentially performs linear search, so it doesn't scale well with the number of the values/columns.
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Column, DataFrame}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col

def withMappedColumn(
    df: DataFrame,
    targetName: String,
    value: Column,
    sourceByValue: Map[String, Column],
    defaultSource: Column,
): DataFrame = {
  var target: Column = defaultSource
  sourceByValue.foreach(p => {
    val next = when(value === p._1, p._2)
    target = next.otherwise(target)
  })
  df.withColumn(targetName, target)
}

val df = Seq(
  (1, "IdName", 1, 0, 0, 0, 0),
  (2, "IdLoc", 0, -1, 0, 0, 0),
  (3, "IdPop", 0, 0, 0, 3, 0),
  (4, "IdTop", 0, 0, 0, 2, 0),
  (5, "IdPin", 0, 0, 0, 0, 7),
  (6, "IdTrin", 0, 0, 0, 0, 8),
).toDF("ID", "Name", "AcctIdName", "AcctIdLoc", "AcctIdPop", "AcctIdTop", "AcctIdPin")

val sourceByValue = Seq("Name", "Loc", "Pop", "Top", "Pin")
  .map((value: String) => ("Id" + value, col("AcctId" + value)))
  .toMap

val dfWithAcctId = withMappedColumn(df, "AcctId", col("Name"), sourceByValue, col("AcctIdName"))

dfWithAcctId.show
+---+------+----------+---------+---------+---------+---------+------+
| ID|  Name|AcctIdName|AcctIdLoc|AcctIdPop|AcctIdTop|AcctIdPin|AcctId|
+---+------+----------+---------+---------+---------+---------+------+
|  1|IdName|         1|        0|        0|        0|        0|     1|
|  2| IdLoc|         0|       -1|        0|        0|        0|    -1|
|  3| IdPop|         0|        0|        0|        3|        0|     0|
|  4| IdTop|         0|        0|        0|        2|        0|     2|
|  5| IdPin|         0|        0|        0|        0|        7|     7|
|  6|IdTrin|         0|        0|        0|        0|        8|     0|
+---+------+----------+---------+---------+---------+---------+------+

dfWithAcctId.explain(true)
== Parsed Logical Plan ==
'Project [ID#185, Name#186, ... , CASE WHEN ('Name = IdPin) THEN 'AcctIdPin ELSE CASE WHEN ('Name = IdName) THEN 'AcctIdName ELSE CASE WHEN ('Name = IdTop) THEN 'AcctIdTop ELSE CASE WHEN ('Name = IdPop) THEN 'AcctIdPop ELSE CASE WHEN ('Name = IdLoc) THEN 'AcctIdLoc ELSE 'AcctIdName END END END END END AS AcctId#199]
...

An alternative could be something like broadcasting the map and adding the new column in a udf by doing the map lookup in constant time. This is less flexible though.
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, udf}

val sourceByValue = Seq("Name", "Loc", "Pop", "Top", "Pin")
  .map((value: String) => ("Id" + value, "AcctId" + value))
  .toMap

val broadcastedSourceByValue = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(sourceByValue)

val mapSourceToTargetUdf = udf(
  (
      name: String,
      acctIdName: Int,
      acctIdLoc: Int,
      acctIdPop: Int,
      acctIdTop: Int,
      acctIdPin: Int,
      default: Int,
  ) => {
    val source = if (broadcastedSourceByValue.value.contains(name)) {
      broadcastedSourceByValue.value(name)
    } else {
      null
    }
    source match {
      case "AcctIdName" => acctIdName
      case "AcctIdLoc"  => acctIdLoc
      case "AcctIdPop"  => acctIdPop
      case "AcctIdTop"  => acctIdTop
      case "AcctIdPin"  => acctIdPin
      case _            => default
    }
  }
).withName("mapSourceToTargetUdf")

df.withColumn(
  "AcctId",
  mapSourceToTargetUdf(
    col("Name"),
    col("AcctIdName"),
    col("AcctIdLoc"),
    col("AcctIdPop"),
    col("AcctIdTop"),
    col("AcctIdPin"),
    col("AcctIdName"),
  ),
).explain(true)

== Parsed Logical Plan ==
'Project [ID#30, Name#31, AcctIdName#32, AcctIdLoc#33, AcctIdPop#34, AcctIdTop#35, AcctIdPin#36, mapSourceToTargetUdf('Name, 'AcctIdName, 'AcctIdLoc, 'AcctIdPop, 'AcctIdTop, 'AcctIdPin, 'AcctIdName) AS AcctId#277]
...

